# Assigning Output of For Loop to Variable in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the following output in R.

**E.g.: Cluster 1: opportunities career learning**

```
result <- vector("list",k)
for (i in 1:k) {
    s <- sort(kmeansResult$centers[i,], decreasing=T)
    result[[i]] <- print(paste("Cluster ", i, ": ", sep="", names(s)[1:3]))
}
result
```

However, in my above code, I keep getting "Cluster 1: opportunities" "Cluster 1: learning"      "Cluster 1: career".

The following code works well (Output is - **Cluster 1: opportunities learning career**), but I need to assign the output to a variable (probably a list?) for printing into a HTML file. How can I assign the output of the entire for loop into a variable if I do it this way?

```
for (i in 1:k) {
    cat(paste("Cluster ", i, ": ", sep=""))
    s <- sort(kmeansResult$centers[i,], decreasing=T)
    cat(names(s)[1:3], "\n")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `?paste`:

> If the arguments are vectors, they are concatenated term-by-term to give a character vector result. Vector arguments are recycled as needed, with zero-length arguments being recycled to "".
>
> ...
>
> If a value is specified for collapse, the values in the result are then concatenated into a single string, with the elements being separated by the value of collapse.

So you want to add `collapse = " "` somewhere in your string munging. Specifically, like this (you don't need `print` either).

```
result[[i]] <- paste0("Cluster ", i, ": ", paste(names(s)[1:3], collapse=" "))
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know the existence of paste0. Your code snippet helped me a lot. My output is now as follows, which is what I expected:

## [[1]]
## [1] "Cluster 1: opportunities learning career"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "Cluster 2: people ground development"
##

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: No problem. `paste0` was only introduced recently (last year?) so a lot of people don't know about it yet.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `lapply` here:

- no side effect
- no need to pre-allocate before looping

For example:

```
res <- lapply(1:k,function(i) {
    cat(paste("Cluster ", i, ": ", sep=""))
    s <- sort(kmeansResult$centers[i,], decreasing=T)
    names(s)[1:3]
})
```